# Observable not updating when removing items

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2, angular2-observables

Using angularfire2 I'm trying to flatten data by joining a user's friend requests with the respective users using forkJoin. I'm doing the following:

```
getFriendRequests(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.afDb.list('friend-requests/' + userId)
        .mergeMap((friendRequests) => {
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                friendRequests.map((user) => {
                    console.log(user);
                    return this.afDb.object('users/' + user.$key).take(1);
                })
            );
        });
}
```

It works fine, it updates when I add a new user to the list. However, when I remove one, the subscription doesn't seem to update. The list is still the same (not just in the view).

```
cancelFriendRequest(userId, friendUserId) {
    return this.afDb.object('friend-requests/' + userId + '/' + friendUserId).remove();
}
```

And on component:

```
this.friendRequestsSubscription = this.friendService.getFriendRequests(this.userService.getCurrentUser().uid).subscribe((friendRequests) => {
    console.log(friendRequests);
    this.friendRequests = friendRequests;
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!